# Does Cloudflare cache redirect location (URL) or response from redirect location?

Tags: cloudflare, browser-cache, cache-control

I wonder how Cloudflare caching works and behaves with redirection. I don't seem to find documentation regarding that but let me know if I missed it.

Suppose I redirect a user from location `https://website.com/image.png` (the caching is configured here) to location `https://3dparty.storage.com/image.png` (cannot configure caching here since it's a 3d party service) and the latest location returns an image `image.png`.

Will Cloudflare cache the image or just a redirection location `https://storage.website.com/image.png`? In other words, when someone accesses `https://website.com/image` for the second time, will Cloudflare return a cached image `image.png` or will it just remember that it's a redirect and basically automatically redirect a user to `https://3dparty.storage.com/image.ong` with no image cached.

Answer (score 1):

By default Cloudflare cached 301/302 redirects, but only for specific file extensions (PNG is included in this list), you can find more info here: [default-cached-file-extensions](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/concepts/default-cache-behavior/#default-cached-file-extensions).

But need to keep in mind that directives `cache-control` and `expires` response header should not present in the redirected resource (`https://3dparty.storage.com/image.png` in your example).
Find more info on this doc: [configure-cache-status-code](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/how-to/configure-cache-status-code/#edge-ttl).

In conclusion, for cache specific redirect you need:

- Create Page Rule with caching settings specific for that url;
- Make sure that 3d party service don't set "cache-control directive or expires response header"